# How to get List of Launching apps

Tags: android, android-package-managers, launching-application

I would like to store the  package name when user launch the application.When user open a application i would like to get that package name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: due to privacy protection, there is no way. You are not allowed to know, which apps are launched by user

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if API version < 21, but not newer version. Look at GET_TASKS permission:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_TASKS

This can be easily abused so it is good to deprecate it.